# Unable to connect to the webserver. Verify that the web server is running and that incoming http requests are not blocked by a firewall

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Asp.Net web code using the Local IIS Web server Version 7 (Windows 7 x64), Framework 4.0.
 I came across the error:-
                    Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to connect to the webserver. Verify that the web server is running and that incoming http requests are not blocked by a firewall.
Pls, help me to overcome this error......

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Reply me...........ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? I am guessing you want to debug your web site running in IIS?

Try publishing the web site to your IIS and starting the site in your web browser. Then do an "Attach to Process" from the Debug menu in Visual Studio. To do this select the process listed as w3wp.exe from the list. Note: If you have multiple IIS web sites that are all running there could be multiple w3wp.exe entries in the list.